# 2 different height DIVs reach top and bottom same time on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 DIVs that will always be a different height because content changes depending on the page. I want these 2 different height DIVs reach top and bottom of the page at the same time on scroll.

Here is a working example of what I'm trying to achieve - http://jsfiddle.net/eBk5f/

The problem is, when the CONTENT DIV has less content than the CONTENT-SIDEBAR DIV and doesn't stretch below the page, the scrollbar disappears and the functionality is lost.

Example of the problem here - http://jsfiddle.net/nESaT/

How do I keep the functionality of the working example regardless of the height of content in either DIV?

EDIT: UPDATED WORKING EXAMPLE SCRIPT WITH BODY CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/TAyXD/

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var doc = $(window);
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $("#content-sidebar").css('top', (calculateScrollSpeed()));
});

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    $("#content-sidebar").css('top', (calculateScrollSpeed()));
});

function calculateScrollSpeed() {
    var leftPaneHeight = $('#content').height();
    var rightPaneHeight = $('#content-sidebar').height();
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();
    var leftPaneScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log((browserHeight - rightPaneHeight) / (browserHeight - leftPaneHeight));
    return -$(window).scrollTop() * ((browserHeight - rightPaneHeight) / (browserHeight - leftPaneHeight));
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working solution!

**The jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
    var sidebarHeight = $('#content-sidebar').height();
    function setup(leftPaneHeight, rightPaneHeight) {
        if (leftPaneHeight > rightPaneHeight) {
            $("#content-sidebar").css('position', 'fixed');
        } else {
            $("#content").css('position', 'fixed');
        }
    }
    function calculate(leftPaneHeight, rightPaneHeight) {
        var browserHeight = $(window).height();
        var scrollerPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (leftPaneHeight > rightPaneHeight) {
            var result = (-scrollerPosition * ((browserHeight - rightPaneHeight) / (browserHeight - leftPaneHeight)));
            return $("#content-sidebar").css('top', result + 'px');
        } else {
            var result = (-scrollerPosition * ((browserHeight - leftPaneHeight) / (browserHeight - rightPaneHeight)));
            return $("#content").css('top', result + 'px');
        }
    }
    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        calculate(contentHeight, sidebarHeight);
    });
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        calculate(contentHeight, sidebarHeight);
    });
    setup(contentHeight, sidebarHeight);
});
```

The CSS:

```
#content {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
#content-sidebar {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

I hope that the code is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

What's going wrong here is that `#content-sidebar` has it's position set as fixed which means it's removed from the document layout.

This means that content in `#content-sidebar` does not actually affect the height of the `body`. While the content in the `body` does not fill the height of the `body` the window will not scroll.

In order to alleviate this issue, you can simply calculate the height of `#content-sidebar` and set that `+` the height of its offset from the top of the screen ( in case you decide to move it from the top ) and set that as the height of the body, which if higher than the height of the window, will bring back the overflow and scrolling functionality you have implemented.

something like this will do:

```
if($('#content-sidebar').height() > $('#content').height()) {
    $('body').css('height',$('#content-sidebar').offset().top+$('#content-sidebar').height());
}
```

**Example**

- http://jsfiddle.net/ty8x4/