# How to sync scroll speed of 2 different height divs in a parent section and replicate this sample in a website?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is:

- having a website with full width sections,
- each sections are split in two divs,
- `DIV`s have different heights.
  Sometimes the left div is the longest, sometimes it's the right one.

When I scroll in this website, I wouldn't like the divs start at the top and finish at the bottom of the parent section in the same time.

I made some research and tryouts to adapt scroll speed but the problem come when I put a parent to these two divs. I try to adapt code from [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602783/2-different-height-divs-reach-top-and-bottom-same-time-on-scroll):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
  var sidebarHeight = $('#content-sidebar').height();

  function setup(leftPaneHeight, rightPaneHeight) {
    if (leftPaneHeight > rightPaneHeight) {
      $("#content-sidebar").css({
        "position": "absolute"
      });
    } else {
      $("#content-sidebar").css({
        "position": "absolute"
      });
    }
  }

  function calculate(leftPaneHeight, rightPaneHeight) {
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollerPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (leftPaneHeight > rightPaneHeight) {
      var result = (-scrollerPosition * ((browserHeight - rightPaneHeight) / (browserHeight - leftPaneHeight)));
      return $("#content-sidebar").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "margin-top": result + 'px'
      });
    } else {
      var result = (-scrollerPosition * ((browserHeight - leftPaneHeight) / (browserHeight - rightPaneHeight)));
      return $("#content").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "margin-top": result + 'px'
      });
    }
  }
  $(window).bind('resize', function() {
    calculate(contentHeight, sidebarHeight);
  });
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    calculate(contentHeight, sidebarHeight);
  });
  setup(contentHeight, sidebarHeight);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}

header {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#grande {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}

#grande2 {
  background-color: bisque;
  width: 100%;
}

#content,
#content2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

#content-sidebar,
#content-sidebar2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

section {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<section id="grande">
  <div id="content">
    1
    <br /> 2
    <br /> 3
    <br /> 4
    <br /> 5
    <br /> 6
    <br /> 7
    <br /> 8
    <br /> 9
    <br /> 10
    <br /> 11
    <br /> 12
    <br /> 13
    <br /> 14
    <br /> 15
    <br /> 16
    <br /> 17
    <br /> 18
    <br /> 19
    <br /> 20
    <br /> 21
    <br /> 22
    <br /> 23
    <br /> 24
    <br /> 25
    <br /> 26
    <br /> 27
    <br /> 28
    <br /> 29
    <br /> 30
    <br /> 31
    <br /> 32
    <br /> 33
    <br /> 34
    <br /> 35
    <br /> 36
    <br /> END
    <br />
  </div>
  <div id="content-sidebar">
    1
    <br /> 2
    <br /> 3
    <br /> 4
    <br /> 5
    <br /> 6
    <br /> 7
    <br /> 8
    <br /> 9
    <br /> END
    <br/>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="grande2">
  <div id="content2">
    1
    <br /> 2
    <br /> 3
    <br /> 4
    <br /> 5
    <br /> 6
    <br /> 7
    <br /> 8
    <br /> 9
    <br /> 10
    <br /> 11
    <br /> 12
    <br /> 13
    <br /> 14
    <br /> 15
    <br /> 16
    <br /> 17
    <br /> 18
    <br /> 19
    <br /> 20
    <br /> 21
    <br /> 22
    <br /> 23
    <br /> 24
    <br /> 25
    <br /> 26
    <br /> 27
    <br /> 28
    <br /> 29
    <br /> 30
    <br /> 31
    <br /> 32
    <br /> 33
    <br /> 34
    <br /> 35
    <br /> 36
    <br /> END
    <br />
  </div>
  <div id="content-sidebar">
    1
    <br /> 2
    <br /> 3
    <br /> 4
    <br /> 5
    <br /> 6
    <br /> 7
    <br /> 8
    <br /> 9
    <br /> END
    <br/>
  </div>
</section>
```

I also have another version but it making a scroll speed adaptation only with the top of the window point... I adapt it from another question from stackoverflow but can't find it anymore...

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      slowScroll('.main', '.sidebar');
    });

    function slowScroll(obj1, obj2) {
      var long, short;
      if ($(obj1).height() > $(obj2).height()) {
        long = $(obj1);
        short = $(obj2);
      } else {
        long = $(obj2);
        short = $(obj1);
      }
      var lHeight = long.height(); // Height of longest element
      var sHeight = short.height(); // Height of shortest element
      var sLock = lHeight - sHeight; // What position from top the shortest element should lock in at
      var startPos = long.offset().top; // The start position relevant to document (offset from top)
      var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(); // Current value scrolled from top
      var lScrolled = ((scrolled - startPos) >= 0) ? (scrolled - startPos) : 0; // Current value scrolled from start of longest element
      var scrollX = sLock / lHeight; // Scroll multiplier
      var sPos = ((lScrolled * scrollX) <= sLock) ? (lScrolled * scrollX) : sLock; // Scroll position for the shortest element
      short.css({
        transform: 'translate3d(0,' + sPos + 'px,0'
      });
    }
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      slowScroll('.main2', '.sidebar2');
    });

    function slowScroll(obj1, obj2) {
      var long, short;
      if ($(obj1).height() > $(obj2).height()) {
        long = $(obj1);
        short = $(obj2);
      } else {
        long = $(obj2);
        short = $(obj1);
      }
      var lHeight = long.height(); // Height of longest element
      var sHeight = short.height(); // Height of shortest element
      var sLock = lHeight - sHeight; // What position from top the shortest element should lock in at
      var startPos = long.offset().top; // The start position relevant to document (offset from top)
      var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop(); // Current value scrolled from top
      var lScrolled = ((scrolled - startPos) >= 0) ? (scrolled - startPos) : 0; // Current value scrolled from start of longest element
      var scrollX = sLock / lHeight; // Scroll multiplier
      var sPos = ((lScrolled * scrollX) <= sLock) ? (lScrolled * scrollX) : sLock; // Scroll position for the shortest element
      short.css({
        transform: 'translate3d(0,' + sPos + 'px,0'
      });
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  font: 20px/1.1em arial, sans-serif;
  background: white;
}

.container,
.container2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FF00FF;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.main,
.main2 {
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  top: 0;
}

.sidebar,
.sidebar2 {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
}

.container.fixed .sidebar {}

footer {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      yo DEB1•
      <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolorff sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
      occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br>END1
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      DEB1•
      <br>1
      <br />2
      <br />3
      <br />4
      <br />5
      <br />6
      <br />7
      <br />8
      <br />9
      <br />10
      <br />11
      <br />12
      <br />13
      <br />14
      <br />15
      <br />16
      <br />17
      <br />18
      <br />19
      <br />20
      <br />21
      <br />22
      <br />23
      <br />24
      <br />25
      <br />26
      <br />27
      <br />28
      <br />29
      <br />END1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="main2">
      DEB2•
      <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
      occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br>END2
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar2">
      DEB2•
      <br>1
      <br />2
      <br />3
      <br />END2
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Would you consider a javascript plugin such as [ScrollMe?](http://scrollme.nckprsn.com/)

Comment: hi @JavaSpyder , i tried to do this with ScrollMe.js which. It coul'd be very helpful because of its declarative synthax directly in html file. I replace the code to allow percentage on data-translatey (there are forks on github to work with it.) But nothing conclusive yet. Do you think you couI'd find the right combination of markups? I continue investigation on github and find https://github.com/Gran3/parallax-scroll/blob/master/README.md which coul'd be ideal if you read the description,but for now I didn't find the right combination. There is no documentation.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Anybody coul'd help me to solve this problem thanks to this repository? https://github.com/Gran3/parallax-scroll . I am not good at javascript redaction and proofreading... Thanks a lot!

Comment: That library looks like it could be a work in progress - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2w5nch2r/) using the exact code from that repo